# Sitemap not really working in typo3 9.5.x

Tags: typo3, sitemap, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to get a sitemap working in Typo3 9.5.x. If I go to https://domain.tld/?type=1533906435 I get the following page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/typo3/sysext/seo/Resources/Public/CSS/Sitemap.xsl"?>

<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

        <sitemap>
            <loc>https://domain.tld/index.html?sitemap=pages&amp;cHash=38eee382dd3fc2edb80b67944d477100</loc>
            <lastmod>2019-10-07T13:57:04-07:00</lastmod>
        </sitemap>

</sitemapindex>
```

So far so good. But the link in there should take me to the actual sitemap, but instead takes me straight to the root page without any redirection. This happens on 2 different sites. I didn't configure anything special, just enabled the seo system extension and included the static template as described [here](https://steemit.com/typo3/@typo3-freelancer/how-to-create-a-sitemap-xml-in-typo3-version-9-5).

When I submitted the sitemap to Google's Search Console, it said "could not fetch", but the next day the status was "Success" and it discovered URLS. I guess Google crawled the root page and found the links on it.

How do I get the sitemap working or is there a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `index.html` part in the path to the pages sitemap looks weird to me.
Can you please try to open the loc url without the `index.html` part?
If you can see the sitemap then, we have to take a look where this `index.html` is coming from.

Comment: Bingo, that put me on the right track. Just removing "index.html" didn't do it. I had to remove the routeEnhancer in my siteconfig. There I set the following
    routeEnhancers:
        PageTypeSuffix:
           type: PageType
           default: '.html'`
           map: { }
to have each page ending in .html

Comment: Sorry for the formatting in the comment above. Formatting doesn't seem to work in comments.